# HTML code indentation issues

Tags: html, indentation

i been doing a codecadmey course on html one of the task were to make the code so it follows the rules of the The World Wide Web Consortium by 2 space indents.I asked a few people where to put the indentations but every time i try i still cant proceed to the next task. here my code below can anyone help me to put the indentations.!!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Animals Around the World</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1> The Brown Bear </h1>
  <p> The brown bear (Ursus arctos) is native to parts of northern Eurasia and North America. Its conservation status is currently "Least Concern." There are many subspecies within the brown bear species, including the Atlas bear and the Himalayan brown bear.  </p>
  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_bear"    target="_blank"> Learn more </a>
  <p> The following are subspecies of bears: </p>
  
  <ul>               
    <li> Arctos </li>
    <li> Collarus </li>
    <li> Horribilis </li>
    <li> Nelsoni (extinct) </li>
  </ul>
 <p> The following countries have the largest populations of brown bears:  </p>
  <ol>      
    <li> Russia </li>
    <li> United States </li>
    <li> Canada </li>
  </ol>
  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_bear"target="_blank">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/web-101/web101-image_brownbear.jpg" alt="bear photo"/></a>
 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: That `<p>` tag has a tab character instead of two spaces. The one that's henke.

Answer (score 1):

Check your spacing. For instance on the link below you should have a space between the href and the target.

```
  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_bear"target="_blank">
```

Should be

```
  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_bear" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Animals Around the World</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> The Brown Bear </h1>
  <p> The brown bear (Ursus arctos) is native to parts of northern Eurasia and North America. Its conservation status is currently "Least Concern." There are many subspecies within the brown bear species, including the Atlas bear and the Himalayan brown bear.
  </p>
  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_bear" target="_blank"> Learn more </a>
  <p> The following are subspecies of bears: </p>

  <ul>
    <li> Arctos </li>
    <li> Collarus </li>
    <li> Horribilis </li>
    <li> Nelsoni (extinct) </li>
  </ul>
  <p> The following countries have the largest populations of brown bears: </p>
  <ol>
    <li> Russia </li>
    <li> United States </li>
    <li> Canada </li>
  </ol>
  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_bear" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/web-101/web101-image_brownbear.jpg" alt="bear photo" /></a>
</body>

</html>
```

The speediest solution is to use the HTML Tidy tool which you may find available online so that you may download and install it.  But, there are also websites that make that tool freely available for immediate use, such as *codepen.io*.  But, that is actually more effort than you need to expend, given that a tidy tool exists at StackOverflow as part of the functionality that the OP uses to display the HTML code in question.  If the OP were to click the option to edit the posed question, a link is provided ("edit the above snippet") that allows one to edit the code.  If you click that link, you will note on the left side a tidy tool that works on HTML, CSS or JavaScript.  So, you may choose to spend your time efficiently by utilizing this tool to have the desired indented code or else visually scan each line and character of the code to figure out for yourself where the spacing needs adjustment.